# workaround for setting part of attribute (for font-awesome icon) in vue 2 template without interpolation?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, font-awesome, vuejs2

I'm trying to create a component using vue.js, where the component contains a font-awesome icon, which is supplied in template.  For example, I'd like to be able to use `<big-nav-item icon="fa-phone" word="contact">` and have the font-awesome phone icon and the word contact land in my component.

The problem is that font-awesome icons take their identifier in the attributes of the element, and Vue.js 2.0 doesn't seem to want to use interpolation in element attributes.  So the following code fails:

```
Vue.component("big-nav-item", {
    props: ["icon", "word"],
    template: '<div class="three columns"><span class="fa-stack fa-3x"><i class="fa {{ icon }} fa-stack-2x"></i><span class="fa fa-stack-1x" style="margin-top:50%; font-size:20px; font-weight:bold;">{{ word }}</span></span></div>'
});
```

because Vue won't let me pass the fa-phone bit into the component via the template.  Instead it throws an error:

> Interpolation inside attributes has been removed. Use v-bind or the colon shorthand instead. For
>   example, instead of `<div class="{{ val }}">, use <div :class="val">`.

Does anyone know of a good workaround for this?  The only thing I can think of trying, which seems super-awkward, would be to write a method for the component that uses raw string concatenation to build up the entire icon element and then insert the whole thing in the template.  I guess I'll try that if there isn't a standard solution to this problem...

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Essentially, in this case,

```
Vue.component("big-nav-item", {
    props: ["icon", "word"],
    template: `
      <div class="three columns">
        <span class="fa-stack fa-3x">
          <i class="fa fa-stack-2x" :class="icon"></i>
          <span class="fa fa-stack-1x" style="margin-top:50%; font-size:20px; font-weight:bold;">{{ word }}</span>
        </span>
      </div>`
});
```

[Example](https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/vmNNbE?editors=1010).

Comment: oh, that's real clever.  It didn't occur to me that you could just slap a second class declaration on it...

Comment: @PaulGowder The difference is one is bound and the other is static. Vue will combine them. There are a number of ways you could go honestly, but this was easiest in my opinion for your use case.